# Ruby: get web elements inside the Shadow-Root DOM

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, shadow-dom

I'm new to Ruby automation test using cucumber and selenium-webdriver.
I received the source code automation from another guy. The way he find element on page some thing looks like:
element(:error_message) { browser.elements(class: 'input-invalidate') }

Now I need to access the element inside a ShadowRoot, did some researches but could not get answer for the Ruby code.
Below picture is an example, I'd like to get the div tag with id="maincontainer" inside that shadowroot, anyone can help please?

Thanks you
[image: shadowroot element]

Comment: Add selenium tag and watir tag while you are asking question from Ruby Selenium Binding.

Comment: **IF** that DOM node exists at the moment you query; ``document.querySelector("downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#mainContainer")`` should do

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Using Javascript seems to be a work around, look like Selenium still doesn't support Shadow DOM, eh?

Comment: I am more and more of the opinion you shouldn't test with oldskool tools in modern Tools land. Tesla does not fully test the batteries either **after** they are installed in the car. Like batteries, Web Components should be tested as **semi-finished product**. Do you **test** the G4 connection before you use your phone? It either works or it doesn't.

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman Are you even understanding what I am talking about? Selenium doesn't have any way to locate the element inside the shadow DOM.

Comment: That is what I explained, oldskool tools can't test modern technology.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman So you say Selenium is old tool which can't be used for Shadow DOM? But you suggest Javascript to take the element from the DOM,is that fine?

Answer (score 4):

This is now supported in Selenium 4.0, here's a working example:

```
driver.get('http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html')

shadow_host = driver.find_element(id: 'shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(id: 'shadow_content')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also verify that you have [selenium devtools](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-devtools) gem installed, and at least [chrome v96](https://github.com/webnicer/chrome-downloads/tree/master/x64.deb) with newest [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

This will work like Titus pointed out when locating element with Selenium

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html"

shadow_host = browser.driver.find_element(id: 'shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(id: 'shadow_content')
```

You can also locate element with Watir and then call `shadow_root` on  underlying Selenium element

```
shadow_host = browser.div(id: 'shadow_host') #Watir::Div
shadow_root = shadow_host.wd.shadow_root
```

edit: this should also work in theory - converting ShadowRoot to Watir element, but it breaks afterwards.

```
browser.goto "http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html"
shadow_host = browser.div(id: 'shadow_host') #Watir::Div
shadow_root = shadow_host.wd.shadow_root #Selenium::WebDriver::ShadowRoot
watir_shadow = browser.div(element: shadow_root) #Watir::Div
watir_shadow.divs.count #undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

I might be doing something wrong :) best to ask @titusfortner

```
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder.rb:73:in `merge_scope?'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder.rb:50:in `normalize_selector'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder.rb:28:in `build'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:47:in `build'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:18:in `initialize'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/container.rb:28:in `new'
/watirs/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/container.rb:28:in `elements'
```